# How do I hash / un-hash a datafile?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How do I hash / un-hash a datafile. It's going to be a sqlite database.

Comment: There's really no such thing as "un-hashing" something. What, exactly, are you trying to do? Verify the integrity of an untrusted file? Something different?

Comment: Do you mean compress, instead of hash?

Answer (score 0):

Search here for encode/decode instead. Hashing is one way, and is used for verification of passwords, content and the like, where you want to make sure subsequent md5 (or similar) hashes from that content is identical.

Answer (score 0):

It's like getting the salt grains back after you put it into boiling water.  Unhashing is not possible by definition.

Hashing is by definition a one way process. You're hashing the salt grains when you put it into the boiling water. You can't get the grains back, but you can compare the water by taste.

You need a good hash, with good taste buds.